# Removing white lines bordering sliced images when zoom in and out in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, google-chrome

I have a sliced image from Photoshop. I was able to work it into my CSS as a background-image. Oddly it works fine in IE10, but in Google Chrome when I zoom in or out I get these white lines on the edge of the sliced images. I set a colored background in the body or the class but I am still getting white borders. Does anyone know what is causing the white borders on my sliced images and more importantly how do remove them?

[image]

```
.bd-image{

background: 
url(images/orange-dark_01.jpg) 0px 0px / 100% 46px no-repeat,  
url(images/orange-dark_02.jpg)  0px 46px / 100% 60px no-repeat,   
url(images/orange-dark_03.jpg) 0px 106px / 100% 48px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_04.jpg) 0px 154px / 100% 48px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_05.jpg) 0px 202px / 100% 58px no-repeat, 
url(images/orange-dark_06.jpg) 0px 260px / 100% 48px no-repeat, 
url(images/orange-dark_07.jpg)  0px 308px / 100% 50px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_08.jpg)  0px 358px / 100% 36px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_09.jpg)  0px 394px / 100% 40px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_10.jpg)  0px 434px / 100% 50px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_11.jpg)  0px 484px / 100% 64px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_12.jpg)  0px 548px / 100% 52px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_13.jpg)  0px 600px / 100% 42px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_14.jpg)  0px 642px / 100% 62px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_15.jpg)  0px 704px / 100% 46px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_16.jpg)  0px 750px / 100% 48px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_17.jpg)  0px 798px / 100% 56px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_18.jpg)  0px 854px / 100% 64px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_19.jpg)  0px 918px / 100% 52px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_20.jpg)  0px 970px / 100% 50px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_21.jpg)  0px 1020px / 100% 40px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_22.jpg)  0px 1060px / 100% 42px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_23.jpg)  0px 1102px / 100% 52px no-repeat,
url(images/orange-dark_24.jpg) 0px 1154px / 100% 46px no-repeat;
z-index:100;
}

</style>
</head>
<body class="bd-image" onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();">
```

Comment: The real solution is stop using slicing. Nothing in that design requires it.

Comment: actually, I compressed the background image from 1.72mb to 215kb, but it was still loading slower in IE10. So I sliced and compressed the images which made it load faster.There is a lot of JavaScript and CSS on this page. Its a data warehouse in a box.  Many things slow it down,

Comment: I'm afraid ceejayoz is right.  Quit using slicing and do the work to make the background image/sprite you need.

Tools are funny in that no matter how badly you want that nail driven in beating on it with a screwdriver rarely works. :-)